# How to run django in a subpackage

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

My project results are as follows, django in automl/service, in automl/service/worker/suggester.py file has an import `from automl.core import util` and this file imported by views.py, when I run `python service/manage.py runserver` will raise the exception

```
from automl.core import util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'automl'
```

how to solve this problem, does django can not run in a sub package?

```
├── automl
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── base.py
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── demo.py
│   └── service
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── manage.py
│       ├── master
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── urls.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── worker
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── admin.py
│       │   ├── apps.py
│       │   ├── exceptions.py
│       │   ├── models.py
│       │   ├── suggester.py
│       │   ├── tests.py
│       │   ├── urls.py
│       │   └── views.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
├── bin
├── build.sh
├── ci.yml
├── conf
│   └── log_config.json
└── docs
```

Comment: try: `from core import util` . i think the `manage.py` file must be outside the service folder

Comment: did you find the solution?